# BIRT - How does Data Binding works?

Tags: reporting, birt

I'm trying to create my first BIRT report and this data binding thing is confusing the bejeezus out of me.

So I have a data set that's working.

I right clicked my table and selected edit data bindings. I put in display names for all of my columns and changed the datatypes.

That seems to have been saved. But nothing appears on the report.

I then tried dragging columns from my dataset onto the detail band of the table, and when I do that BIRT brings up a (different?) data binding editor where it doesn't have any of the changes I made, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with this one.

**Could someone explain to me the basic process of getting my dataset to show up on a report table, and what all this data binding stuff is supposed to do?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you been through the [tutorials?](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/tutorial/basic/) They answered most of my basic questions, including your other q about templates.

Comment: I think I tried them all.  I'm really not seeing an explanation of the data bindings.  E.g., how and what they do.  Is there one particular that you think explains it, I'll take another look.

Comment: @Greg [This one](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/tutorial/basic/basic06.php) talks about the automatic binding which is the easiest way to go about it (the drag and drop method), I've never really had a problem with using this method if I didn't have to make any alterations to the data I get from the database.